# after multiple brake bleed, lever's max stiffness is still close to bar

Tags: shimano, brakes, hydraulic-disc-brake, brake-levers

so  after a few bleeds i've done on these Shimano saints, because of new levers replacement, i've found that the rear brake lever, although on max stiffness, goes way further to the bar then the other lever (front brake), by around a whole centimetre. I'm sure that there's enough fluid, but is giving the symptoms of not having enough, even though it is full? Can anyone help me as its difficult to get power out of them?

Comment: Have you checked the reach adjust?

Comment: Are the freestroke adjusters equal?

Comment: Do the front and back levers feel the same, the only difference being when each lever hits “max stiffness” as you put it?  Or, does the rear brake lever feel like it slowly creeps up towards max stiffness while the front brake lever hits max stiffness quickly without any spongy feel vs. the rear brake lever?

Comment: @TedHohl  basically, if i put both reach adjusters so it should be on max stiffness, the rear brake lever goes closer to the bar compared to the front, by a whole cm, as if it doesn't have enough fluid in it.

Comment: @mattnz basically, if i put both reach adjusters so it should be on max stiffness, the rear brake lever goes closer to the bar compared to the front, by a whole cm, as if it doesn't have enough fluid in it.

Comment: @AshtonO'Connell, I got that. That additional 1 cm of travel: is it very low resistance or is there a build up of pressure as you hit a firm brake lever?  If there is a steady build up of resistance it would be sign that there could still be a little air in the system somewhere. Air will compress, where brake fluid does not (for all intensive purposes).   If the lever travels easily to a firm lever you may be low on fluid. You have your front brake to compare with.

Comment: Have you checked Freestroke adjust. (as suggested by @MaplePanda)  Reach adjusts how far fromt he bar the lever sits, Freestroke adjusts how soon after the lever starts moving before pads engage.  Not enough fluid is entirely possible if you pads are worn and you are using blocks that are too thick.

Comment: @TedHohl how would i put more fluid inside, if the resevoir looks full?

Comment: @mattnz pads are quite new, both free stroke screw adjusts are both all the way in, and yet the rear brake lever still contacts the pad later then the front when pulled if that makes sense.

Comment: @AshtonO'Connell - I was asking about how the rear lever felt as it approached full on.  That can be a tell if there is air in the system somewhere.  The reservoir could look/be full, but if there is air in the system somewhere else, then you are compressing the air "bubble" which will be a spongy feeling lever.  The same thing applies to automotive brakes as well.  If there is no air in the system, the lever will hit a quick, solid, hard brake feel.  Also note, rear brakes are a little tougher to bleed correctly.  Longer line and you need to orient the bicycle specifically to do it right.

Comment: @AshtonO'Connell - you might check this out:  https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/17832/air-in-hydraulic-brakes-after-bleed

Comment: One diagnostic if you want to isolate the problem further is swap the hoses over and see if the problem stays with the lever or the caliper.  (Does mean a couple of brake bleeds on both front and back brakes)